# Consulta mysql con dos tablas

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla de jugadores donde tengo todos los datos de los jugadores, en este caso el nombre y apellido, después tengo otra tabla donde tengo resultados de partidos, en esa tabla de resultados de partidos tengo dos campos que se llaman, jugador_a y jugador_b (estos dos campos son parte de un mismo registro), esos campos tienen los id que corresponden al id de la tabla de jugadores.
Lo que necesito es saber como obtengo el nombre y apellido de los dos jugadores en una misma consulta. Yo solo puedo obtener el nombre y apellido de uno de los jugadores pero no el de los dos. Dejo la consulta que hice como ejemplo.

```
SELECT nombre.jugadores, apellido.jugadores from jugadores INNER JOIN juegos ON jugadores.id = juegos.jugador_a WHERE id = 170
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tendrías que incluir dos veces la tabla `jugadores` en la consulta, una para relacionarla con la columna `jugador_a` y otra para relacionarla con `jugador_b`. Luego los nombres se obtendrían por cada tabla respectiva (les he dado los alias `a`  y `b` a las tablas para este caso).

La única duda aquí es el `id` del `WHERE`, he asumido que se refiere a la columna `id` de la tabla `juegos`:

```
SELECT 
    a.nombre AS a_nombre,
    a.apellido AS a_apellido,
    b.nombre AS b_nombre,
    b.apellido AS b_apellido
FROM juegos AS j
    INNER JOIN jugadores AS a ON j.jugador_a = a.id
    INNER JOIN jugadores AS b ON j.jugador_b = b.id
WHERE j.id = 170
```